# ember.js - update template from whatever controller observes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am just getting started with ember.js. I want to update a controller's data based on a server request that was made by another controller; i.e: MyController should update its state when the IndexController has changed a property. I think I have that right, but I'm not sure how to update the template based on the observed change. Here's what I have 'til now:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <div>
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <form>
    <label for="go">Data</label>
    <input type="text" id="go" />
    <button type="button" {{action "findData"}}>Find Data</button>
  </form>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="my">
  <ul>
    {{#each entry in controller}}
    <li>{{entry}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

these are the templates which currently are stored in index.html

```
var App = Ember.Application.create()

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  myProperty: false,

  findData: function() {
    console.log("Requesting data from the server ..");
    myProperty = true;
  }
});

App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   needs: ['index'],

   myPropertyHasChanged: function() {
   var propertyChanged = this.get('controllers.index.myProperty');
   if (propertyChanged) {
      console.log("property has changed");
      return ["apple", "orange"];
   }
}.observes('controllers.index.myProperty')
});
```

and this is the actual ember.js code. How can I have the data in the "my" template updated based on whenever the button in the index template is pressed ? It should be a list of 2 elements ("apple" and "orange")

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value of the controller content to the list you want displayed in the `myPropertyHasChanged` function:

```
this.set('content', ["apple", "orange"]);
```